# Equal standard errors for all levels of a categorical factor in lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I have a question about the standard error of mixed model parameters estimated using the `lmerTest` package.

I have 12 sites with 6 treatments over each site. I measured a response variable (`biomass_of_insects`) (which has a Gaussian distribution).

```
library (lmerTest)  
model <- lmer(biomass_of_insects ~ as.factor(treatments) + (1 | sites))
```

However, the model summary shows the same standard error for every treatment (see below: 114.065). Why is the standard error always the same?

```
Fixed effects:        
                       Estimate    Std.err      df       t        p
(Intercept)             501.333     80.656  66.000   6.216 3.91e-08 ***
as.factor(treat)F       126.667    114.065  66.000   1.110    0.271 
as.factor(treat)I        -8.333    114.065  66.000  -0.073    0.942     
as.factor(treat)I+F1/3  -75.000    114.065  66.000  -0.658    0.513   
as.factor(treat)I+F2/3   18.333    114.065  66.000   0.161    0.873    
as.factor(treat)I+F3/3   15.917    114.065  66.000   0.140    0.889
```

Comment: this is now cross-posted in (at least) three places: R-help, StackOverflow, and here.  Please don't do that!  Since this is probably the most appropriate venue, I'm going to copy my answer from there to here and vote for closure/deletion there (it would be better if you deleted your question there yourself).

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is "because there's the same amount of information in the data about each treatment" -- your data are balanced.  I'll illustrate with the `Product` effect standard errors from the `ham` example included with the `lmerTest` package. Computing `with(ham,table(Product))` shows the data are balanced with respect to `Product`.  The standard errors *would* differ if the data were unbalanced, as for example:

```
library("lmerTest")
## model of balanced data: summary(m) will give identical std errs
m <- lmer(Informed.liking ~ Gender+Information+Product +
   (1|Consumer), data=ham) 
## now randomly sample half the data set (very unlikely to produce a 
##  balanced data set)
set.seed(101); dd <- ham[sample(nrow(ham),size=nrow(ham)/2),]
with(dd,table(Product))   
## Product
##  1  2  3  4 
## 82 78 80 84 
summary(update(m,data=dd))
...
##              Estimate Std. Error t value
## Product2     -0.25309    0.31769  -0.797
## Product3      0.56563    0.31676   1.786
## Product4      0.31761    0.31035   1.023
```

The standard errors are still very similar (because the data set is only slightly unbalanced), but no longer identical.

Comment: How does this not cause an issue with differently scaled variables?

Comment: not clear what you mean.  This phenomenon occurs when we have a categorical predictor with a balanced design.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm having a similar issue within a multivariate space with three repeated measure DV's, one of which is scaled differently than the other two. Since it is scaled differently, the standard errors are inflating p-values. I think