# Can we perform a post-hoc comparison to 2 groups, which are interacting with time, using a linear mixed model in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, post-hoc

I wonder if it is correct way to obtain p-values by comparing 2 groups which are interacting with time, using post-hoc following a linear mixed model computation.
Here an example of nerve measurement as electrical outcome. A indicates left (group 1) and B indicates right (group 2).

> Subject=(S1A, S2A, S3A, S4A, S1B, S2B, S3B, S4B)
>   Group=(1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)

As you may see above, there are 2 groups of 8 subjects from same individuals and the signal was recorded as a function of time. As a result I have used a linear mixed model.

```
library(nlme)

> outcome = lme(signals~group*time, data=dt,random=~1|subject)
> summary(outcome )
```

I obtained a result as seen in the image [image]. Then, I have applied Tukey pairwise comparison

```
library(emmeans)
Tukey<-emmeans(outcome , list(pairwise ~ group| Time), adjust = "tukey")
Tukey
summ <- summary(Tukey[[2]])
```

Here is the result,[image]

I wonder if I can/should use post-hoc comparison for 2 groups. When I compute two cases: a linear mixed model and Tukey, it gives completely different result. I do not know which is the correct one of comparing these two groups as a function of time. Additionally may I kindly ask if you can explain me what does time (image 1-red), group:time(image 1-black) and 1-2 at 0 sec (image 2) indicate? Group=condition, I wrote condition instead of group in the code when I tried before.

Last, if post-hoc for time intereaction can be used, can I use bonferroni or benjamini hochberg test instead of Tukey to reduce false error.

PS: the p-values are computed using dummy values. I have once seen the differences (between 2 groups) based on interaction (time) could be computed with post-hoc.

Comment: If you didn’t want a Tukey adjustment, why did you specify that??? Look at `? summary.emmGrid` and the documentation for `adjust`. There are several choices.

Comment: @rvl thank you for your reply. With my respect, I didn't understand what you mean by your questions. May I kindly ask if you can explain me. Unfortunately, my knowledge in terms of statistics is a bit limited. Therefore, I apologize for annoying questions.

Comment: The sets of coefficient estimates you are getting are equivalent. The emmeans summary is just giving them to you in scientific notation. For condition2:time 1, the regression coefficient is -.0178915 and emmeans reports a comparison of condition 1 and 2 at time 1 of -1.789141e-02. Same thing.

Comment: @ErikRuzek If I am not mistaken applying emmans is correct if I want to compare condition 1 and 2 at each degree in a linear mixed model, am I correct? So, what I did was actually correct since the coefficient is same. May I ask why do the p-values are different between 1-2 and condition2:time1, while the regression coefficient is same? They should provide the same p value, isnt it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The p-value is different, but you if you are basing your decision of significance on the p-value, then the conclusion would be similar. The difference is likely a reflection of the exact test used across the two procedures. `lme` is not using Tukey's HSD whereas `emmeans` is. What seems strange to me is the standard errors all being the same for any coefficient involving the time variable.

Comment: @ErikRuzek thank you for your great help and sorry for the annoying questions. **but you if you are basing your decision of significance on the p-value, then the conclusion would be similar.** unfortunately, I didn't fully understand this. If the p-values are different, how the conclusion would be similar? To better understand, emmans uses outcome of lme and defining the p-values of group difference based on the time interaction. I did not fully understand if applying lme and emmans is the correct choice or just lme here for this condition.

Comment: @ErikRuzek why do you think the std errors are same? Do you think it may cause any errors?

Comment: Typically, people choose an alpha level (cutoff p-value) for determining significance. Often, that is p<.05. So if you are using that criterion, in neither the `lme` nor `emmeans` results would you conclude that the interactions were significantly different from 0. In terms of the standard errors, I believe it is because your time variable must be balanced, meaning that you have equal number of observations for each time value. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170018/equal-standard-errors-for-all-levels-of-a-categorical-factor-in-lmer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103896/discussion-between-tim-and-erik-ruzek).